# How to validate that at least one field out of four has an input from the user

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have four fields on my screen and I want the user to at least enter a value for one of the fields. I want a popup message similar to what you can do with a validate control to popup when none of the fields have a value entered.

Is there a way to do this with the stock validate control in ASP.NET?

I know how to do this is JavaScript, I just wanted to see if there was an easier way first.

Comment: It seems that there are no simple solution that will give you nice result. As example, FluentValidation library (for ASP.NET MVC) can provide you nice syntax for server-side validation. With using of your `ModelClientValidationRule` you also need to add new validation rule through using of jQuery.validator. Talking about just ASP.NET, it seems that validation problems are the same.

Comment: Also, there is a way to use ajax remote validation on server, but that is bad idea anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you can validate this using a groupbox control